# Classic ASP - REMOTE_HOST variable

Tags: asp-classic, vb6

I have a classic asp application (intranet based) that uses the following statement:

```
Host = request.servervariables("REMOTE_HOST")
```

The host variable is then passed to a VB6 function, which enters the address into a database table.  I have setup the application on my local PC, which involves publishing the classic ASP app to IIS7 and running the VB6 app in debug mode.  If I use the app on my local PC by navigating to: `http://localhost/website`, I have noticed the Host is similar to the following: "::1" when I connect locally, but when a remote user access the application, the IP address is correct e.g. 172.x.y.z.  What is ::1?

Answer (score 1):

::1 is the IPv6 equvilant of 127.0.0.1

If you have both IPv6 and IPv4 on the box, IPv6 takes precedence.

If it's a big problem for you, you can disable the IPv6 stack - but it's probably better to just live live with it.

Comment: The IP address is 'fe80::f5a8:420:71d1:5431%11' if I enter the full domain name i.e. http://computername/website.

Comment: That is likely your global IPv6 address